# Matching users flow Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, multithreading, express

So i'm trying to create a system which users can match each other by specific information,
the flow i have in mind is as follows:

1. user 1 fills the information and clicks "find"
2. at the same time user 2 does the same as user 1
3. the client sends a request to the server in route /X so the server can push the client to a (threadsafe)queue
4. a worker thread pulls out from the queue each time and do the matching
5. meanwhile the user polls route /Y in the server to get his match
6. the worker thread finds 2 users match and pushes it to some (threadsafe)data structure
7. next time the user polls the server(in /Y), the user gets the match and is redirected to the conversation

so first of all is this a good approach?
and also is using a worker thread and threadsafe datastructure logical in javascript?(specifically Nodejs and express) is there an alternative or a better way to do this kind of stuff?

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bad approach.

You do not need (and should not use) worker threads for your use case.

## On Worker Threads

Worker Threads are isolated instances of Javascript which run as a separate thread. They are intended strictly for performing CPU-intensive work.

## vs vanilla Node

But you don't need them, because Node libraries are asynchronous, which means that unless your code really is CPU-intensive, you won't see any benefit from using Worker Threads (in fact there is overhead to using them, so if they aren't needed, your code will run *slower*).

From the [docs](https://nodejs.org/api/worker_threads.html): "Workers (threads) are useful for performing CPU-intensive JavaScript operations. They will not help much with I/O-intensive work. Node.js’s built-in asynchronous I/O operations are more efficient than Workers can be."

## More on Threadedness

Javascript is single-threaded, and works very well that way. There is no concept of "threadsafe" in Javascript, because it isn't needed; all code is threadsafe.

## If you do have CPU-intensive code

If you're doing expensive regex matching, then you are right to want to run this code in parallel. Worker Threads might not be the best way to do this, though.

Splitting CPU-intensive code into separate programs is often the most flexible solution. It gives you several options:

1. spawn a new instance of Node run your CPU-intensive code (on the same server)
2. run your CPU-intensive code in the cloud on "serverless" services, such AWS Lambda
3. turn your CPU-intensive code into a "microservice", essentially a tiny webserver which does any specialized processing and returns the result

## Further Reading

How Node's asynchronicity works (big picture)
https://blog.insiderattack.net/event-loop-and-the-big-picture-nodejs-event-loop-part-1-1cb67a182810

What kinds of operations block the event loop and how to avoid it
https://nodejs.org/uk/docs/guides/dont-block-the-event-loop/

Comment: ok but how one can achieve this kind of behavior?
i'm used to c/c++ multi-threading concepts.
i need to have a background process which takes care of matching constantly.
is it better to just match the users whenever they send a request(pick a matching user from the pool and return it)?

Comment: @someone what exactly does the "matching" do? I'll need more information about that step

Comment: for example you enter the website, you fill some information about yourself
and you press the "find" button, then the website matches you with another person who was also looking for another person at the same time. then you can talk together in a chat. same like omegle/chat roullete

Comment: @someone that sounds like something that will be backed by a database, in which case you should still use only asynchronous calls for maximum performance. Even if you handle it internally with data structures, it doesn't sound very CPU-intensive, so you should continue with an asynchronous workflow. Of course in C/C++, there needs to be a separate thread/process for this but in Node it's not needed. Everything is essentially in an event loop, so you can handle web requests in parallel with extra work. That functionality is out of the box with express

Comment: if i understand well the event loop isn't concurrent so i don't have to worry about synchronizing data structures?

Comment: @someone correct! No concurrency, no pre-empting of code, and no need to worry about synchronization.

Comment: @someone just to be clear, there's a typo on my comment above (and too late to edit it): "Everything is essentially in an event loop, so you can handle web requests in parallel with**out** extra work. That functionality is out of the box with express". Should read "without extra work" and not "with extra work".